# :eq doesnt select second div while select first | jquery

Tags: jquery

**edit:**

certainperformance said that the code works on test page but it doesn't work on my website.so to give more information, I share code snippet from my website:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name="location"]', function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      $(".ea-standard form div.step").not(':eq(0),:eq(1)').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ea-standard">
  <form novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="step">
      <div class="block">
      </div>
      <label class="ea-label">Location</label>
      <select name="location" data-c="location" class="filter valid" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
        <option value="2">Newyork Clinic</option>
        <option value="1">Center Hospital</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="step" style="display: none;">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <label class="ea-label">Service</label>
      <select name="service" data-c="service" class="filter" data-currency="$">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
        <option data-duration="60" data-slot_step="60" value="2" data-price="430.00">Neurology 430.00$</option>
        <option data-duration="60" data-slot_step="60" value="1" data-price="350.00">Cardiology 350.00$</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

if you want to check my website:

https://www.video.helvatica.com/

you can find the form modal with click appointment now button on homepage:

[image]

---

I have multi selectable form element under form and when select an option from first selectable form element, I want to hide all selectable form elements which has step class except first and second ones.

However, my code show only first one, not also second.

how to write correct code?

Comment: You can use `.ea-standard form div.step:gt(1)`

Comment: You could also `$(<selector>).slice(2).hide()`

Comment: `.hide()` will hide the selected elements, it won't show the other ones if they're previously hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show all items before hiding some

```
if ($(this).val() !== '') {
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").show(); //show all
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").not(':eq(0),:eq(1)').hide(); //then hide some
}
```

Comment: A shorter way could be `$(".ea-standard form div.step").show().filter((i)=>i>1).hide()` ;)